# signal generation model in Simulink from matlab

Tags: matlab, signals, simulink

How do I generate following signal in simulink:

```
t=(0:1000)/1000*10*pi;
```

I want to build the model of the following matlab code:

```
t=(0:1000)/1000*10*pi; 
x = (t).*sin(t);
y = (t).*cos(t);
z = t;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fairly basic stuff. Have you gone through any Simulink tutorial, introduction videos/webinars or even the getting started guide of the documentation?

Here are a few suggestions to help you answer your question:

1. Set the stop time of your model to 1000s and use a fixed-step solver with a step time of 1s.
2. Use a [Clock](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/clock.html) block with a decimation of 1. That's your `0:1000` vector.
3. Feed the output of your Clock block to a [Gain](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/gain.html) block, with the gain set to `1/(10000*pi)`. That's your `t` vector.
4. Feed your `t` signal to two [Trigonometric Function](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/trigonometricfunction.html) blocks, one set to `sin` and one set to `cos`. That will generate two signals, `sin(t)` and `cos(t)`.
5. Now multiply your `t` signal with your `sin(t)` signal using a [Product](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/product.html) block, to generate your `x` signal (`t*sin(t)`).
6. Do the same thing with `t` and `cos(t)` to generate your `y` signal. `z` is already done since it's equal to `t`.

**EDIT following comments**

The answer to your comment is really basic Simulink stuff. You should learn how to use Simulink before trying to do advance stuff like VR in Simulink. It's a bit like trying to run before you can walk.

Here are a few resources that may be useful:

- [Simulink Videos and Examples](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/simulink/examples.html)
- [Simulink Webinars](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/simulink/webinars.html)
- [Simulink tutorial](https://www.mathworks.co.uk/academia/student_center/tutorials/slregister.html)
- [Getting Started with Simulink](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/getting-started-with-simulink.html) in the Simulink Documentation

I don't know much about VRML, but be aware that the coordinate system in VRML is different from that in MATLAB/Simulink (see http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/sl3d/vrml.html). You should also have a look at [Virtual World Connection to a Model](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/sl3d/associate-a-virtual-world-with-a-simulink-block.html) in the Simulink 3D Animation documentation.

Comment: There are some quires as i'm new to Simulink but have craze to learn it very fast, THnkX for your suggestion, pls guide me more that how can I do step 1 and where to connect its output?
moreover i designed step 2 to 6 model, how can I send there output to VR Signal Expander in order to move a ball in designed model?

Comment: @user3108320 See my edited answer. Learn how to use Simulink first, then try more advanced stuff like VR.